# How to display Attribute Group Name on compare page?

Tags: group, compare

I used [this](http://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/How-to-display-Attribute-Group-Name-on-Product-page/m-p/12156/highlight/true#M2490) guide and was able to display the attribute group name on the product page, but I'm wondering how to do the same on the compare page ? I'm using magento ce 1.9.2.1 with custom Porto theme if that is important. 
Thank you

Comment: What happen when you add that code to your compare page template?

Comment: From the forum I linked
"Go to magento root directory and follow below steps:
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes.php copy Attributes.php file and paste 
\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes.php here and Edit Attributes.php file 
Add this code after Line number 82 "
I did this and then I had to replace the code in app\design\frontend\MyPakage\MyTheme\template\catalog\product\view\attributes.phtml , but my porto theme uses the default product attributes.phtml

Comment: So I replaced it's code but the attribute tab in the product page doesn't show. I combined the two codes and came up with this http://gamingtech.bg/down/attributes.zip

Answer (score 0):

I found what i needed - [StrApp Multitab Product View & Compare](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/strapp-multitab-product-view-compare.html)
But the website is down so i can't purchase it. Does someone know how to add this functionality with code ( i already have attribute groups in product page ) ?
Or is there another module that does this ?